# Where can i view the source code in System.IdentityModel.Services namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, wif, ws-federation

This if my first foray into .net source code. I'm trying to understand the event handlers in `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` so I can override them successfully.

I downloaded the .net source (4.5.1) from [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com). When I opened the solution I found the System.IdentityModel project but there is no project for System.IdentityModel.Services, nor does it exist as a subclass of System.IdentityModel.

I've searched the entire solution for `WSFederationAuthenticationModule`, but it doesn't exist. My expectation was to see a one-for-one mapping of what I see in Intellisense with the projects and classes in the ndp.sln.

Can someone shed some light on why the source doesn't map to the namespaces and classes in the compiled framework and/or tell me where I can get the source code for `System.IdentityModel.Services`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ do not represent the complete set of assemblies available in .NET.

> As you can probably notice, the set of assemblies that we have is not
>   complete. We don't intend to keep it that way, so we plan to expand
>   the set of assemblies over time.

[A new look for .NET Reference Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx), Immo Landwerth

On the same post quoted before you can find how to contact Microsoft about requesting new assemblies to be made available, given that they are probably added in terms of priority and how many people are actually wanting to browse those assemblies.

Having said that I already went through the process you're about to embark and the dotPeek decompiled source was enough for my needs, so you may want to try that while the actual source code is not available.

Answer (score 1):

`WSFederationAuthenticationModule` class is located in the `System.IdentityModel.Services` assembly, in `System.IdentityModel.Services.dll`, which itself is located in your GAC. You can see the source code using a decompiler like dotPeek or ILSpy.